# Automatic numbering of report

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am looking for a code in Delphi 7 that helps to generating an automatic numbering of a quickreport when a user prints or views the report. My main idea is to use the code in a report as a receipt that shows how many receipts have been used or printed. I would appreciate on any information on how to write the code using a quick report.

Answer (score 0):

QuickReports offers no support for automatic numbering like you're asking. (It supports automatic page numbering, but not tracking things like the last number of something printed for use the next time like a receipt or invoice number.)

You'll need to keep track of the last number used somewhere yourself, in a database, INI file, or whatever best suits your needs.

When you print a receipt, you read the last value used from that storage, update it, write it back to the storage, and then assign that new number to a label on your receipt (you can use the `QRLabel.OnPrint` event for that - just use `Value :=  IntToStr(NewReceiptNumber);`, where `NewReceiptNumber` is the variable holding the receipt number).

Comment: Thanks Ken. your  idea is very good. I will try and do as you  have said